# Restyle slider handles in Primesfaces Framework

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I've been curious whether and how it is possible to change the look of Primefaces' sliders in a way that doesn't ruin the components look, i.e. quite a few styles are applied to these components and thus e.g changing the color to red would require me to also change a bunch of other style attributes.

Is there any smooth way?

Comment: _"Is there any smooth way?"_ Other than using a different theme or downloading the component source and changing that: no

Comment: Well its only few css lines (for a component), example: `.ui-slider .ui-slider-range { background: red; }` .

Comment: @OuerghiYassine: If the only style the op wants to change is the background color you are right, but I doubt that is the case considering the explicit mentioning of _"also change a bunch of other styles"_. Looks the OP investigated that to some extend.

Comment: Yeah.. In the case of the background color, changing it to red would actually paint most of the handle red but there would still remain a fine blue outline which is neither the actual outline nor border property... I guess due to the fact that Primefaces components are composite and not a single entity. I'd be grateful if someone could also try that out, maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: @Wecherowski anything can be done in css i guess, if you can be more precise maybe we could help.For the handles, they are using a sprite image: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/javax.faces.resource/images/slider_handles.png.xhtml?ln=primefaces-omega